# Excel - Trying to work out a simpler way of expressing Nested If Statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, statements

I have looked high and low and understand about nested if statements my question relates to using many if statements in the one cell. My formula is as follows:

```
=IF(F2= "win",E2,0)+IF(F3="win",E3,0)+IF(F4="win",E4,0)+IF(F5="win",E5,0)+IF(F6="win",E6,0)+IF(F7="win",E7,0)+IF(F8="win",E8,0)+IF(F9="win",E9,0)
```

Now this works fine but as I enter each new data entry I require a new if statement to relate to the next row. I am sure there is a way of doing it but the other ways I thought would work always result in an error and I have resorted to doing this and when getting to the end of my data I insert a new if statement to relate to the row. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use a combination of SUMIF and COUNTIF?

Answer (score 1):

This formula will accomplish the same thing and lends itself to be a little easier to modify.

```
=SUMIF(F2:F9,"=win",E2:E9)
```

Now you can modify this to include the entire column so that you don't have to change your formula when a new row is added like this:

```
=SUMIF(F:F,"=win",E:E)
```

Here is what my test data looked like:

[image]